# Making sense of a strange set to set mapping

Tags: functions, special-functions

Suppose I have a function $f$ defined as

$$f(y) = \{z \in [0, 1] \mid (ay-c) z \leq (ay - c)x\}$$

Where $y \in [0, 1], x \in [0, 1]$ and $ a, c \in \mathbb{R}$

Then claim:

- $f(z) = 0$ if  $(ay-c) > 0$
- $f(z) = [0, 1]$ if  $(ay-c) = 0$
- $f(z) = 1$ if  $(ay-c) < 0$

For the life of me I cannot reason out the $(ay-c) > 0$ and $(ay-c) < 0$ cases.

Can someone please clarify how they were able to arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** In those cases, the quantity is nonzero, so you can divide both sides of the defining inequality by it (in case it is positive, the inequality sign remains the same; in case it is negative, the inequality sign reverses). So the inequality will become either $$z\leq x$$ or $$z\geq x$$ Does that help?

Comment: Yes I recognize that the equality sign changes but why is it in those cases $z$ has to be 0 or 1?

Comment: Does the inequality have to hold for **all** $x\in[0,1]$?